# Bond price under the risk-neutral measure

Tags: bond, risk-neutral-measure

Could you point out where I am making mistake in the process below?

> 

It follows from the term structure equation and the Feynman-Kac theorem that the bond price is given by

$
p(t,T) = E_t^Q\left[ \exp\left( -\int_t^T r(u) du \right) \right],
$

where $E_t^Q$ denotes the expectation at time $t$ under the risk neutral measure $Q$.

Let the money market account be

$
B(t) = \exp\left( \int_0^t r(u) du \right),
$

and the bond price expression above is written as

$
p(t,T) = E_t^Q\left[\frac{B(t)}{B(T)} \right].
$

Since the numeraire of $Q$ is $B$, it follows from the martingale property that

$
E_t^Q\left[ \frac{B(t)}{B(T)} \right]
= E_t^Q\left[ \frac{B(t)}{B(t)} \right] 
= 1.
$

Thus, $p(t,T)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

No, $B$ is not a $Q$ martingale, neither is $1/B$, which you have assumed in your calculation (try using constant $r$, for an example of why this can be the case). The measure $Q$ is a risk neutral measure if the stock price processes that are discounted by $B$ are martingales.

Comment: Thank you so much.
Now I know from your answer that $\frac{B(t)}{B(T)}$ is not a martingale under $Q$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your argument slightly mixed up. Assuming the existence of a risk-neutral measure $Q$, you know from the risk-neutral pricing formula that the discounted bond price is a martingale, i.e. ($D(t)$ being the discount factor)
$$D(t)p(t,T) = E_t^Q[D(T)p(T,T)] = E_t^Q[D(T)].$$
With $D(t) = \mathrm{exp}(-\int_0^t r(u) du)$, we immediately get
$$p(t,T) = \frac{1}{D(t)}E_t^Q[D(T)] = E_t^Q[-\int_t^T r(u) du].$$
Therefore, the equation for the bond price includes already the numeraire. Using it again wouldn't make sense.
Also, without further information about $r(t)$, it is not possible to derive an exact solution for the bond price.